# Validate zip file in java

Tags: java, validation, zip

I have zipped a folder containing files and folders using zip4j in Java. I want to validate created zip for -

- The number of files chosen before zipped?
- Whether files are not being corrupted during zip process?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

What I'd do is extract the folder to a different location, use the standard POSIX `find` and `cmp` commands to compare the corresponding files in the original and extracted directories.

Answer (score 0):

Please read through this snippet .
http://www.java-examples.com/get-crc-32-checksum-zip-entry-example

You can catch the execption for the invalid checking of the file.

Look at the following snippet

```
while(e.hasMoreElements())
{
    ZipEntry entry = (ZipEntry)e.nextElement();

    /*
     * To get CRC-32 checksum of an entry, use
     *
     * long getCrc()
     * method of Java ZipEntry class.
     *
     * This method returns the CRC checksum for a particular
     * zip entry, or -1 if not known.
     */                            

    String entryName = entry.getName();
    long crc = entry.getCrc();

    System.out.print(entryName);
    System.out.print("\t\t\t\t" + crc);
    System.out.print("\n");
}
```

You can use this code and insert a static counter to count the files inside the zip.
Coupling this code to your zipping logic should work just fine.

Comment: Does this answer help?   If there are no more questions please close the question with whatever response / resolution code you would like.